# How to add different children in each section of an expandable list view in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view. It has 4 sections. 
In the first two sections i want to display text. 
In third one i want to display image and in fourth one i want to display a video.
In short every parent is having a different child. 
How to implement this in an expandable list in android?

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ExpandableListAdapter where you return different types of views depending on what group the item is in.

So in your list adapter you override

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and do something depending on the groupPosition, for example

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (groupPosition == 0) return text views for this child
if (groupPositon == 1) return image views for this child
}
```

That should get your started. It's quite easy from there.

Comment: Thanks monkjack :) I'll try this out and will let u know.

Comment: Hey monkjack, I tried doing the way u told, but each and every child is showing me both the text view and images whereas in condition i put that i want to display text in only first and second sections and image in the remaining two. Can u plz help me out? Plz tell me that where i am going wrong. I cannot post my complete source code because of less space so i am posting another question where i'll post source code. Will u plz look at it and try to tell that what is going wrong?

Comment: did u solve issue.. It seems it's just "not perfect" if-else logic.. please write about ur solution or accept given answer.. 10q

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending CursorTreeAdapter to make your ExpandableListAdapter, you should manage creating the different types of views in newChildView() and binding them in bindChildView(). You can use the data in the Cursor to differentiate between the different cases.

**Example code**

```
    @Override
    protected View newChildView(
        Context context,
        Cursor cursor,
        boolean isLastChild,
        ViewGroup parent )
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        String firstColumnName = cursor.getColumnName( 0 );
        if( firstColumnName.equals( "_id" )) {
            return mInflater.inflate( R.layout.main_list_item, parent, false );                
        } else if( firstColumnName.equals( "name" )){
            return mInflater.inflate( R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false );                
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown firstColumnName:"
                + firstColumnName );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindChildView(
        View view,
        Context context,
        Cursor cursor,
        boolean isLastChild )
    {
        String firstColumnName = cursor.getColumnName( 0 );
        if( firstColumnName.equals( "_id" )) {
            bindMainView( view, context, cursor, isLastChild );
        } else if( firstColumnName.equals( "name" )){
            bindSearchView( view, context, cursor, isLastChild );
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown firstColumnName:"
                + firstColumnName );
        }
    }
```